# Referring to abstract type members in class constructors in Scala

Tags: scala, type-members

I can have a field referring to an abstract type member in Scala, e.g.

```
abstract class C {
  type T
  val t: T
}
```

but it seems that I cannot do the same thing for a constructor parameter:

```
abstract class C(t: T) { // not found: type T
  type T
}
```

Why?

Comment: Main reason why you can not do this way is how polymorphism implemented in scala. Answers to you question will covers quite a big number of areas which will take some time to explain. Try read next article: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html and dig around type parameters and also implicit's if need deeper understanding.

Answer (score 3):

The first line of definition of a class is a constructor, so it is independant of a given implementation of the class (since you're building it, you cannot know the abstract type member yet).

However, what you can do is give a type parameter to your class:

```
abstract class C[T](c: T) {
}
```

So that `T` can be used in the constructor (which is just a type-dependant method, now). Note that type parameters and members are two different things, so you cannot do this:

```
val stringC = new C("foo") {}  // the {} enables instantiation of abstract classes
val other: stringC.T = "bar"
```

If you want to use `stringC.T` notation, you need to define a type member which is equal to your type parameter:

```
class C[A](c: A) {
  type T = A
}
```